Host File in Azure Windows VM Gets Blank Intermittently
I have a Windows Server 2022 Standard virtual machine running on Azure. Recently, I've encountered an issue where the host file (C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) intermittently gets blanked out without any apparent reason.
Here are some details:

The VM is in a resource group and is located in Central US.

It has 16 vCPUs and 64 GiB of memory.

There is no public IP address associated with the VM.

It is part of a specific virtual network and subnet.
So far, I've tried the following without success:

Ensuring there are no scheduled tasks or scripts that might be modifying the host file.

Checking for any antivirus or security software that might be interfering.

Reviewing the system event logs for any suspicious activities around the times the host file gets cleared.
Has anyone else experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this further?


Has anyone else experienced a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this further?

This question has nothing to do with programming. Please ask your question on a suitable StackExchange website.

The host file will delete automatically if the values are missing. You may delete the existing content and replace it with site content from here This method will resolve the auto-delete host file issue.


Host File in Azure Windows VM Gets Blank Intermittently

There are some reasons why the host file might be empty. You can check the steps below to resolve the issue.

Make sure to check if anyone is modifying the file by enabling the audit option for the /etc folder.
The host file may be reset or erased if the necessary content is not present in it.
Delete the existing data in the hostfile and replace it with the content below.


Note: Make sure to open Notepad with administrator , navigate to below path in Notepad, and save the file.

C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Restart the device after updating the hostfile.
Hostfile
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   ::1             localhost

